# How to generate a contentscript.js dynamically after Chrome Extension installation?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to generate contentscriptA.js, contentscriptB.js, contentscriptC.js so I can later inject their content on specific sites I visit.

I want to create them *after* the extension is installed in the browser.

I did not find how to actually create them inside the extension. I've looked into [contentscript API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#extension-files) and also external libs like [chromestore](https://github.com/summera/chromestore.js) (which only create files in a separate filesystem)

Comment: There is probably a better solution for whatever you want to accomplish. Why exactly are a background script, a content script and injected scripts not enough?

Comment: webNavigation API + chrome.tabs.executeScript with `code` string, the code can be stored in chrome.storage.local, for example